# iOS - Framework files showing when app crashes from integrated base project

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I have created a framework and integrated into the base project for execution case my framework implementation may miss out like:

- array out of  bounds error
- null pointer exception

For this type of scenarios, the app crashed due to the above exception  (test.framework) at the same time framework implementation files showing only when the app crashed.

Please let me know if there is a way to fix it?

[image]

Reference : https://instabug.com/blog/ios-binary-framework/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your framework contains debug information which includes file locations.

Since you are using the same machine, lldb debugger is able to locate the source code where your app crashed.

**You can move the Framework's Xcode project to different location on your Mac to see the difference.**

Comment: Is there a workaround to fix this? I would still want my apps to be in the same directory as my framework's Xcode project.